# Android timepicker - remove the above and bottom rows

Tags: android, user-interface, timepicker

I'd like to have my TimePicker have only one row instead of the three to use less of the screen. Here's a picture of the 3 row TimePicker.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you should go for custom Time Picker then. create 3 lists similar to TimePicker

Comment: @AliAhmed How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Actually is searched for 1 line Time picker but didn't find any. I got a thought that its possible with 3 lists. in First list you have numbers from 1 to 12, in Second List you have number from 00 to 59, in 3rd List you can place A.M, P.M.

Comment: @AliAhmed what do you mean by list? A number picker? That also has 3 rows